# Sound keeps playing on Sprite Kit game

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, audio, sprite-kit

I used this code to loop a song in my Sprite Kit game but when I go out of the app/game the song keeps playing and I don't know how to stop the song when you get off the game:

```
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"deep-blue-sea" ofType:@"wav"]];
    _sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    _sound.delegate = self;
    _sound.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [_sound play];
```

Please can someone help me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UIApplicationDelegate`protocol has a method called `applicationWillResignActive:`. [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html) says:

> This method is called to let your app know that it is about to move from the active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the app and it begins the transition to the background state. An app in the inactive state continues to run but does not dispatch incoming events to responders.
>
> You should use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game. An app in the inactive state should do minimal work while it waits to transition to either the active or background state.

Perfect time to stop the music!  `AVAudioPlayer` has a `stop` method to stop playing, just like the `play` method starts playing.  You mentioned in a comment that you're audio player is in an SKScene.  So I would create a method on your scene that stops the music:

```
-(void)stopMusic {
    [_player stop];
}
```

and then call the method in `AppDelegate`.

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [scene stopMusic];    //scene is your SKScene subclass
}
```

Comment: Thank you but do I have to implement the AVAudioPlayer framework in AppDelegate.h to use the stop method? And I've declared the _sound property in a SKScene, how do I use it in AppDelegate?